# How to properly test destructors in Python?

Tags: python, testing, destructor

I want to test that the destructor of a Python object is called and works properly, i.e. it doesn't raise any error nor returns a bad exit code.

I am stuck in writing the unit test, because it seems that the unit test finishes before the object is deleted.
I did not manage to force the object to be deleted before the test returns, and I can't afford to call `__del__` directly in my tests for two reasons:

- That's not exactly what I'm testing
- This actually ends up in the object being destroyed twice, and in my case the destructor frees some memory so it creates a segmentation fault when called twice.

To illustrate this, I've created a toy example where I have two objects. The first one, `MyWrongObject`, contains a bug in the destructor and the second one `MyCorrectObject` is correct.
I've written tests for each of these objects. One should succeed while the other should fail.

```py
import unittest
import gc


class MyWrongObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.del_calls = 0

    def __del__(self):
        if self.del_calls:
            # Something really bad can happen here like a segmentation fault
            # because we may free some memory twice
            raise AssertionError("Already destroyed")
        self.del_calls += 1

        # Simulate an error
        raise ValueError("Error while destroying the object")


class MyCorrectObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.del_calls = 0

    def __del__(self):
        if self.del_calls:
            # Something really bad can happen here like a segmentation fault
            # because we may free some memory twice
            raise AssertionError("Already destroyed")
        self.del_calls += 1

        # No error here


class TestDestructor(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_correct_object_should_destroy_itself(self):
        # Given
        my_object = MyCorrectObject()

        # When / Then
        del my_object
        gc.collect()

    # This test should fail
    def test_my_wrong_object_should_destroy_itself(self):
        # Given
        my_object = MyWrongObject()

        # When / Then
        del my_object
        gc.collect()
```

In the current state, both tests succeed, with the second one printing the `ValueError` in stdout:

```sh
python -m unittest snips_nlu.tests.test_destructor.TestDestructor                                                                                                     1 ↵
.Exception ignored in: <bound method MyWrongObject.__del__ of <snips_nlu.tests.test_destructor.MyWrongObject object at 0x1118bbda0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adrien/dev/snips-nlu/snips_nlu/tests/test_destructor.py", line 17, in __del__
    raise ValueError("Error while destroying the object")
ValueError: Error while destroying the object
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.044s

OK
```

I can't manage to write these tests in a consistent way (using the same code in both), and have the first one pass while the second one fails (without any `AssertionError` in the stdout).

Thanks for your help!